# difference between assignment operator and type conversion funtion for converting user defined to another user defined

Tags: inheritance, c++11, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Assignment operator: allow implicit conversion from a particular type on assignments.
// Type-cast operator: allow implicit conversion to a particular type.

class car;

class bus
{

public:bus & operator = (car & b)
                                // implicit conversion by assignment operator
  {
    cout << endl << "Assignment operator of BUS " << endl;
    return *this;
  }

/*  operator  car () const      //    Type-cast operator
  {
    return (car ());            // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class car’
  }*/
};
class car
{
public:
  car ()
  {
  }
  car (const bus & b1)
  {
    cout << endl << "conversion constructor";
  }
  car & operator = (bus & b)    // implicit conversion by assignment operator
  {
    cout << endl << "Assignment operator of car " << endl;
    return *this;
  }
operator   bus () const       //    Type-cast operator
  {
    cout << endl << "Typecast operator-in car" << endl;
    return (bus ());
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  bus b;
  car c1 = b;                   // call convertion constructor of car object

  c1 = b;                       // call assignment operator of car
  // or 
  b = c1;                       // call assignment operator of bus

  car c2; 
  bus b2 = bus (c2);            //call   Type-cast operator of car`enter code here`

  // we cannot define  Type-cast operator in bus 
  // eventhough forward decleration is done 
  // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class car’
  // so car c=car(b)  is not possible
```

My question is implicit conversion from user defined type to another type
       1) if assignment operator declared in both can serve purpose for bus = car and car = bus
          then why complicated syntax of Type-cast operator is used? is there any  difference
          if so ?
       2) Is there is any relation between copy constructor and convertion constructor mentioned   above ,one similarity i noticed is both call while assigning and argument passed copyconstructor and convertion constructor are different.Is there other difference or similarities.
       3) Eventhough forward decleration is done there is an error:" invalid use of incomplete type ‘class car’" that code is commented ,Why?

Thanks In advance

Comment: You have an impossible loop: Your `bus` class needs a fully defined `car` class, and the `car` class needs a fully defined `bus` class. You need to find a way to break this loop, perhaps by having a common base-class (it feels kind of natural that both `bus` and `car` would inherit something like e.g. `vehicle`), perhaps this base class could be using the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't see why you can't just use out-of-class member function definitions for this one.

Comment: @T.C. Of course, I just wasn't sure that the actual declaration of the type-cast operator needed the full definition as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim Pileborg mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443663/difference-between-assignment-operator-and-type-conversion-funtion-for-convertin#comment43326576_27443663), you can use CRTP to accomplish what you need:

```
// code could stand for more tidying, but you get the idea
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

// Assignment operator: allow implicit conversion from a particular type on assignments.
// Type-cast operator: allow implicit conversion to a particular type.

template <typename T>
class Car
{
public:
  Car () = default;
  Car (const T & b1)
  {
    cout << endl << "conversion constructor to " << typeid(T).name();
  }
  Car & operator = (T & b)    // implicit conversion by assignment operator
  {
    cout << endl << "Assignment operator of car to " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
    return *this;
  }

  T type() const
  {
    cout << endl << "Typecast operator-in car to " << typeid(T).name() << endl;

    return T();
  }
};

class Bus : public Car<Bus>
{

public:
   Bus() = default;
   Bus(Car<Bus>& b)
   {
      *this = b;
   }

   Bus & operator = (Car<Bus> & b)  // implicit conversion by assignment operator
   {
      cout << endl << "Assignment operator of BUS " << endl;
      return *this;
   }

   Car  car () const      //  Type-cast operator
   {
      return Car<Bus>::type();
   }
};


int main ()
{
   Bus b;
   Car<Bus> c1 = b;                   // call convertion constructor of car object

   c1 = b;                       // call assignment operator of car
   // or 
   b = c1;                       // call assignment operator of bus

   Car<Bus> c2; 
   Bus b2 = Bus (c2);            //call   Type-cast operator of car
   return 0;
}
```

CRTP, or the curiously recurring template pattern, allows us to use templates so that a base class can know about a derived class.

In this case, we made `Car` a templated class, and a `Bus` derives from `Car<Bus>`, allowing us to perform conversions in the `Car` class to a `Bus`.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/EFw5Ox)

---

To answer your questions:

1. If assignment operator declared in both can serve purpose for bus = car and car = bus then why complicated syntax of Type-cast operator is used?

The problem here is that `Car` needs to know about the full implementation of `Bus` and `Bus` needs to know about the full implementation of `Car`. See the circular reference here? Templating, or forward-declaring and using pointers allows us to work around this.

2. Is there is any relation between copy constructor and conversion constructor mentioned

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here, but I'll take a stab. A constructor accepting another type could be viewed as a 'copy constructor' that is performing conversion, but that's likely what you meant by 'conversion constructor'.

3. Even though forward declaration is done there is an error:" invalid use of incomplete type ‘class car’" Why?

This brings us back to #1 and circular references. You can use pointers to get around it if you forward-declare.

Comment: "The problem here is that Car needs to know about the full implementation of Bus and Bus needs to know about the full implementation of Car." No they don't. Neither class definitions require the full definition of the other; some member function bodies do, but that's easily solved by defining them outside the class definition.

Comment: @T.C. You're right about this specific use case. I assumed OP was doing something a little more complicated than what is given here. Perhaps it's overkill.

Comment: Thanks experts for answers